# How to work with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib

One of the graph generation files of Python is Matplotlib("http://matplotlib.org/"). 
I am using Python3.2.1 on Windows7(64bit) O/S. 
I am trying to download the same to run matplotlib.animation.

If any one of the esteemed members of the group may kindly suggest me how to download 
the same.

Thanks in Advance,
Regards,
Subhabrata Banerjee.

I can not import matplotlib.pyplot/matplotlib.pylab and if I have to download where from I may download? I am using Python3.2.1 on Windows7(64 bit). 
But without a separate download how come matplotlib.animation is fine?
Regards,
Subhabrata.

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe full support of python 3 has been added to matplotlib. Here is [the status page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-py3/wiki/).

[It will support it on the next release](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/whats_new.html).

If you want to use matplotlib with python. I believe you should use python 2.7 because Python 3 has massive changes that broke backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) to install the `matplotlib` by following command:
`pip install matplotlib`

It will automatically handle download and dependency task for you.

For how to install `pip` under Windows, refer here: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)